# Trigger.io: Android Issue Access Origin Policy

Tags: trigger.io

Trigger.io has just updated today and we found the new UI great! But when we run our Application to android Emulator, we suddenly found this issue:

`[ERROR] XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://site.com/api/. Origin content://com.sample.android.app is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. -- From line 1 of null
[ERROR] Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o -- From line 1 of`

We are trying to access the api and then an error occured. It is working fine in Iphone but having a trouble in Android.

I hope trigger.io can address this issue please.

Answer (score 3):

Trigger apps on Android are served via content:// urls which means they are not permitted to make requests to other domains, on iOS file:// urls are used so this restriction is not in place.

You have 2 options to fix this, either set the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header sent by the server to `*`, or use `forge.request.ajax` to make the request. `forge.request.ajax` uses native code to make the request and so avoids any Javascript security limitations, more documentation is available here: https://trigger.io/docs/current/api/modules/request.html